# Set the width of BIRT crosstab cell from script

Tags: birt

How can i set the with of crosstab cell from the events?
I tried doing

```
 this.width="0in";
```

from onCreate() event but it does not work. I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to hide the cell, you might try something like this, in your crosstab script:

```
function onCreateCell( cellInst, reportContext )
{
    if (cellInst.getCellID() == cellID#){
        cellInst.getStyle().setDisplay("none");
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the actual post that this comes from.  It shows another option, for setting the actual width: http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/22736-dynamically-change-column-width-cross-tab/